# How to add a comment to Trello card via API calls?

Tags: python, trello

I am testing Trello API via Postman and I have a problem adding a comment to a card.

I'm submitting a PUT request to `https://api.trello.com/1/cards/card id/actions/commentCard/comments?&key=my_key&token=my_token&text=comment`, but I receive an error:

> invalid value for idAction

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a `commentCard` `idAction` when you list the actions `GET board/[board_id]/actions` for the board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Trello API you need `POST /1/cards/[card id or shortlink]/actions/comments`. Please see [Trello API](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#post-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-actions-comments)

Answer (score 0):

you try POST to

`https://api.trello.com/1/cards/cardID/actions/comments?text=yourComment&key=apiKey&token=trelloToken`

where you must change the variables `cardI`, `yourComment`, `apiKey` and `trelloToken` to your variables

Answer (score 0):

for inserting a comment, these parameters are required :
1: id   //The ID of the Card
2: key  // API key
3: token
4: text  // your desired comment

so, if you want to use postman to do it, use the below URL and set the method to POST

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{id}/actions/comments? 
key=""&token=""&text=""
```

instead of {id} --> insert your card id

key="" ---> then insert your private Key and token

text=""  ---> then insert your comment in " "